# Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "title". Expected String with value **, got Number with value **

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my code below, i'm using Vue js and i'm showing data from JSON API so here in modal the `title` should be dynamic and i wrote it as below, it worked when clicked twice but at the first click i got the error mentioned above. Also it crashed the cancel button which is `hidemodal()` function
can somebody help?

```js
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'light-table',
    components: {

    },
    data() {
      return {
          modalShow: false,
          buildingId: null,
          Building:[],
        projects,
        currentPage: 1
      };
    },

methods:{
 showModal(buildingId) {
      this.$root.$emit("bv::show::modal", "modal-1", "#btnShow");
      this.buildingId = buildingId;
          
    },

    hideModal() {
      this.$refs["my-modal"].hide();
    },
    
mounted: function(){
    BuildingsService.getOneBuilding(`${this.$route.params.id}`).then((response) => {
      this.Building = response.data.response;

console.log(this.Building.floors,"data floor");

    });

    }
  
},}
</script>
```

```html
<b-modal  v-for="(flatno,index) in Building.flats" :key="index"  v-if="flatno._id.includes(buildingId)"
            id="modal-1"
          
            :title="flatno.flat_number"
            ref="my-modal"
            hide-footer
          >

           <b-textarea
              id="question-input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Description Proposal"
            v-bind:active-hover="true"
              required
            />
            <br />
            <b-row class="input-info">
              <input
                class="price-info"
                type="number"
                placeholder="price Offer"
               
                required
              />

              <select class="currency-info" >
                <option value="" selected disabled>Currency</option>
                <!-- <option>American Dollar</option> -->
                <option>Turkish Lira</option>
              </select>
            </b-row>

            <br />
            <input
              class="delivery-input"
              type="number"
              placeholder="delivery time"
             
              required
            />
            <br />

            <footer id="modal-1___BV_modal_footer_" class="modal-footer">
              <b-button
                class="cancel-button"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                target="_blank"
                @click="hideModal()"
                >Cancel</b-button
              >
              <b-button
                class="answer-button"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                target="_blank"
                @click="PostSolution()"
                >submit</b-button
              >
            </footer>
       
  </b-modal>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: @match it's coming from title `<b-modal  v-for="(flatno,index) in Building.flats" :key="index"  v-if="flatno._id.includes(buildingId)"
            id="modal-1"
          
            :title="flatno.flat_number"
            ref="my-modal"
            hide-footer
          >`

Answer (score 2):

If the error is with `title` then the problem is that the `title` prop expects the value to be a string, but you are passing in a number:

```
:title="flatno.flat_number"
```

You should cast this value to a string:

```
:title="flatno.flat_number.toString()"
```

Comment: thank you it worked, but it still crashes the hidemodal() method which is on cancel button

Comment: also.. didn't work from the first click i should click double to appear